# Laptop Touchpad Disable Touch to Click

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I'm struggling to get the terminology right on this one. I have one of the more modern touch-pads: Dell Inspiron 15 (7548) and want to disable the "light touch" to click. I've previously been using a MacBook Air and want my Dell to behave in the same way (needing a proper hard click, not just a touch).

Is this possible? Everything I've found so far talks about disabling clicking via the touch-pad altogether, but I can't find anything specifically for disabling the "light touch" to click.

Answer (score 1):

If "disable touch to click" is an option, it will be in the touchpad software.  It is usually accessible from Control Panel -> Mouse or from the touchpad system tray icon.

If the option isn't present.  You may try updating the touchpad driver/software.

Comment: I can't find that option and i'm not sure if that's actually what I want (would that prevent me clicking using the touchpad completely?)

Comment: And there doesn't appear to be a driver for it (windows automatically recognizes it)